# How do I deploy a .NET MVC6 Web Application to Amazon

Tags: .net, azure, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I run a .Net set of web services with a sql db on Windows Azure, what is the common practice approach for getting this migrated over to AWS headache free these days? (I'm migrating over as AWS dangled a large amount of free hosting credit carrot, enough for me to be motivated to learn a new tech stack).

Edit: I managed to figure out through piecing together a few tutorials/docs and trial and error (Long story short, it wasn't trivial). Will summarise the steps required and answer this when I have time.

Comment: Why the [tag:azure] tag?

Comment: Oh I've just edited the question to explain why, essentially the question is specifically meant to be asking for the migration process of a .net MVC web app instance from Windows Azure to AWS EC2. The general process may seem easy and straight forward on the surface, but there are many gotchas to work through and consider, for example, setting up SSL, handling multiple web apps on a single EC2 instance, the cost/benefit of using AWS beanstalk load balancer over a single instance. Which I'm going to write a brief blog article about as I dont think anyone has really covered this process properly